# Como cambia el color de fondo en python con tkinter

Tags: python-3.x

Hola me en cuentro con un problema como cambia el color de una interfaz con tkinter en python o sea quiero cambiar el color de fondo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero usar lo siguiente `ventana.configure(background='#7c1324')`, en donde los caracteres que van después del numeral (#), es el color que le quieres dejar.

Aqui dejo un enlace con la escala de colores [Escala de Colores](https://html-color-codes.info/codigos-de-colores-hexadecimales/)